# Obtaining the connector name from the converter code

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am writing a custom converter for Kafka Connect. How do I obtain the connector name from the converter code?

Comment: Please clarify your use case. Converters should not be coupled with user supplied strings